Identifying the electrical components in an LC resonant inductive coupling circuit
I am trying to identify the electronic components of this circuit. I am very new to this, obviously.


Any chance anyone here might be able to help ... please ask about the component, not about the odds of receiving assistance

The more information you can provide about what device it is part of the more likely you will get a response.

It looks like you have shown the receiver part and that the device has been modified. The "L" part of the "L-C" is the copper coil on the perimeter of the device. I guess the "C" part is composed of two small translucent tan coloured objects sandwiched between two black objects with polarity marking double stripes (diodes).  Is this device in your possession or have you simply been presented with a picture of it.?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

These are they electronics of the circuit that is used to hydrolyze water in the body to supply oxygen to the cells in the device. The hydrogen is allowed to dissipate out of the body. As someone stated it is part of a device implanted under the skin and then powered by a device on the skin that supplies the power. It is designed to resonate at 13.56MHz. The oxygen generation needs to be regulated so not too much or little is supplied to the cells. I have larger pic of the device, but not sure how to post another pic with this question.

It's an implantable device for continuous, injection-free diabetes treatment.
The device has no battery on board. Instead, an external power source emits radio waves that are picked up by a receiver on the device, generating electrical current. The process, known as inductive coupling, is commonly used to wirelessly charge smartphones and other devices.
More information here.
The possibility of identifying the components in that picture is remote.
